# Can I ask GHC to import Debug.Trace for every module during development?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I often add traces when debugging, which requires adding the `Debug.Trace` import. However, I equally often forget about removing those when I'm done.

What I'd like would be a "dev" switch which would add the import, so that when I disable it I could easily find all of the traces left in the code.

Comment: Why not import `trace` from an internal `.Utils` module rather than directly from `Debug.Trace`, and delete the export of `trace` from that module when you are done?

Comment: @Michael hah, that's actually a good idea. IOW, should be an answer :)

Comment: Actually, one could craft an "OnOffTrace" module where a compiler flag determined that export. Maybe that's something worth putting on Hackage. I like the Util more in that it looks less intrusive though. However, the *ideal* solution wouldn't require adding any imports at all.

Answer (score 4):

Why not import trace from an internal .Utils module rather than directly from Debug.Trace, and delete the export of `trace` from that module when you are done?

It's different, but another expedient I picked up somewhere is to toggle between `trace _ = id` and `import Debug.Trace (trace)`. Then you can e.g. go back and forth between using (real) `trace` and doing things like benchmarking, which is of course wrecked by `trace`. Then when you are done with all that, you can delete the export of (either) `trace` and hunt down all the remaining evidence that you ever used it in your project...